# Installing open corpus work bench

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I tried to install the open corpus work bench cwb http://cwb.sourceforge.net/ via the terminal. I followed the given instructions but terminal always answers "command not found"

I use ubuntu 14.04.

Can anybody help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are downloading the wrong file.

Just go to the [Downloads](http://cwb.sourceforge.net/download.php) page and download `cwb-3.0.0-linux-i386.tar.gz` if your OS is a 32bit one or `cwb-3.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz` if you are using a 64bit Ubuntu version.

If you dont know which architecture you have you can write in a terminal `uname -p` to find out.

After that, just extract that file to some place (your desktop, for example), and use a terminal to navigate there and run the installation script:

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/cwb-3.0.0-linux-x86_64
$ sudo ./install-cwb.sh
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your help! Installation completed.

I forgot to navigate to the desktop :(